# How to get Xmllint to read from stdin?

Tags: xmllint

- I don't want to create an XML file
- I need to use the --shell with cat to create filters
- I don't have xpath in my version of xmllint, using `libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6.x86_64`

  `xml|xmllint --shell - <<< $(echo 'cat /')`

  `-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found`

EDIT: `clustat -x` outputs an XML file and I want to parse out the active node.
I don't think there is a way to do it without xpath so I created a temp xml file.

```
/usr/sbin/clustat -x > /tmp/clustat.xml
ACTIVENODE=$(xmllint --shell /tmp/clustat.xml <<< `echo 'cat //group/@owner'`|grep -v "^/ >"|cut -d= -f2|tr -d \")
```

Answer (score 72):

I had a similar issue where I had to unzip an XML file then feed it to **xmllint**. The key is the "-" option which tells **xmllint** to read from **stdin**.

For example:

```
$ bzip2 -dc dierehabilitati00delagoog_meta.xml.bz2 | xmllint --format
```

would fail giving the "usage" for xmllint. Adding "-" worked:

```
$ bzip2 -dc dierehabilitati00delagoog_meta.xml.bz2 | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
  <title>Die Rehabilitation im Strafrecht</title>
  <creator>Ernst Delaquis</creator>
  <mediatype>texts</mediatype>
  <collection>americana</collection>
</metadata>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, this will work from stdin but can you also create filters?

Comment: I'm not familiar with clustat, but I used sed to pull the values for a tag. Ex: bzip2 -dc dierehabilitati00delagoog_meta.xml.bz2 | xmllint --format - |  sed -n 's|<[creator]*>\(.*\)<[creator/]*>|\1|p' would return "Ernst Delaquis"